# Many British country pubs are called 'The Stag' what would a French pub be called?

Tags: anglais

[image: this is a pic of what I'm enquiring about - maybe the French pubs use the boar or similar more than deer etc]
Pretty much everything I'm asking is in the question head, thanks

Comment: Welcome to [FL](https://french.stackexchange.com/help). France doesn't have pubs as such. Where there is one it is often called "pub (something or other)" to get a British look.  A more relevant question would be to ask for a popular name for a *café* (or maybe *bar* or *brasserie* - although I'm not sure such a question would fit the site's rules). By the way I don't agree with you about *the stag* being a typical name for a country pub, *Fox & Hounds* & *The Plough*  for example  are way ahead where country pubs are concerned.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I'm really hoping for a French equivalent of "The Stag" - do country village/towns just have 'Hotel de Smith St' as their name? nothing colourful like the seven ducks (or whatever)? cheers

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Hotel names? Inn name? café names? A popular [*auberge*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auberge) name in the countryside I can think of straight away is *Auberge du Val* (with variants *auberge du petit val*, *auberge du val fleuri* ...). Those kind of places rarely have the owner's name. *Auberges* are found in small places, not in cities. *Le relais de poste* is also quite common and typical of country areas.

Comment: If you're looking for animal names a rather frequent  (but not very picturesque to my mind) name for hotels - not specially in country areas - is *Au Lion d'or*  because of the play on words ( *au lit on dor* → *au lion d'or*)

Comment: - *Le **Balto***

Comment: https://www.lebarbiche.fr/le-cerf-volant/ **Le Cerf-Volant** Mind the play on words.

Answer (score 1):

You do find a good number of "Café du Cerf"'s, although there are other places such as hotels and restaurants that bear that name; the name might be "Au Cerf" or "Le Cerf".

[Cerf](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=caf%C3%A9+du+cerf)

It is quite similar to Britain, where the word "stag" is used to name not only pubs but also inns and restaurants.

[Stag](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=the+stag%2C+pubs+in+Britain)

There is another equivalent in France, provided you tolerate a little shift in the type of establishment you are considering; it is not often going to be a café but instead it'll be an inn or hotel (where there is bound to be a bar and/or lounge). The privileged animal, not wild this time but fully domesticated, is the horse, and without exception, the white horse or the black horse. You'll find in all parts of the country  the names "Auberge du cheval blanc" and  "Hôtel du cheval blanc", "Le cheval Blanc", etc.

[Cheval Blanc](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Auberge+du+cheval+blanc)

[Cheval Noir](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=auberge+du+cheval+noir)

You do find  in Britain an exact correspondence for this last cultural trait since there the word "horse" is often used in the names of places such as pubs, restaurants and inns, a few of these inns being as well pubs.

"[White Horse](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=White+Horse+inn%2CBritain)"

Answer (score 0):

There are four main types of names of pubs you could find in France as far as I know.

- Names related to [some cultural aspect of the city](https://goo.gl/maps/TuHgq42SrA4paH2v5), region you are in (la bonne mère, la tour eiffel...)
- [British names](https://goo.gl/maps/VJ1cFWf6BDAJWTHr8) (Shannon, Shamrock, Black Horse....)
- [Puns on names](https://goo.gl/maps/jsScYiWp7r8agDdk8) including names starting with " O' ". I believe these are so common (restaurants, fast foods, cafes, pubs..) because of the pun.  "Au soleil" would be "O' Soleil", and that would imply that your pub has a nice, sunny terrace
- [Name of someone, probably the owner](https://g.page/lecafedeflore?share) -> "Chez Marie", "La maison de Ben"...

Comment: What has O Soleil got to do with pubs?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the **O** in pub name is rather a way to sound irish (like Kitty O'sheas in Paris (and in many other place))

Comment: @Archemar The 'O' is indeed a way to sound irish. However, in french, it is also used to make puns (ie : O'Délices, O'Tacos, O'Epices, L'O à la bouche....).  I don't think tacos sellers/french restaurants want to sound irish